# jQuery outerHeight is not working when reattaching an element

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I create div containing an image and attach it to an iframe.To determine the height iframe with the div, I use the jQuery.outerHeight on the div by attaching it the body. The first time I do it, it returns the correct value. But when I remove this div from iframe and try to reattach it the another iframe again, jQuery.outerHeight doesn't work again.  It doesn't calculate the padding of the div.

Answer (score 1):

I understand, it is because JavaScript handles the frame to a full load of all elements of the frame. I placed an event:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    //here is cod
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: jQuery can't measure something if it is not visible. Are you sure the element is visible when you reattach it?

Comment: I have not set the div to be hidden.The outerHeight(true) is able to get the div's height without padding.